# Create functions to automatically calculate probabilities with R

Tags: r

I want to automatically calculate the probability with R. Rule : start with 0 points. We will flip a coin. If it comes up heads, we get a point. If comes up tails, we double our current score.

The functions I want to code:

- Expected score after n flips (5flips, 15 flips...)
- After n flips, what is the probability the score is a power of two (Express this probability as a number between 0 and 1)?
- Standard deviation
- The expected standard deviation of the scores?

I want my functions to adapt to rule changes. For example, 2/3 probability of heads, and a 1/3 probability of tails. What is our expected score after 10flips?

Answer (score 0):

First, you want to think about what parameters the function needs to take.  It appears it just needs to take the parameter `n` - the number of flips.

```
flips <- function(n){

}
```

Now, you can think about what needs to happen inside the function.

1. start with 0 points
2. add 1 if heads
3. double if tails

You also need to be able to do this `n` times, so it will need to be in a loop.

```
flips <- function(n){
## start with 0
sum <- 0
for(i in 1:n){
  # create a flip (random draw of H or T) 
  flip <- sample(c("H", "T"), 1)
  # identify what to do if flip is H
  if(flip == "H"){
    # increment sum by 1
    sum <- sum + 1
  # identify what to do if flip is not H (i.e., it is T)
  }else{
    sum <- sum*2
  }
  }
# return the sum
sum
}
flips(10)
# [1] 28
```

A function like this will code after `n` trials, what happens.  That said, it seems like the questions you're trying to answer are more theoretical than they are about coding.  If you can specify the operations you need to do, then we could probably help you code it.

Comment: The score is not stable. When I try f(10) the score varies with each launch.

Comment: It is a random process so it will be different each time. Presumably that is why you asked about expectations of the process.

Comment: I'm sorry if the question was not clear. But I updated. I don't know much R

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can start with building a function `f` like below which produces a series of random variables, where `0` and `1` denote head and tail respectively

```
f <- function(n,p) {
  v <- sample(c(0,1),n,replace = TRUE,prob = c(p,1-p))
  s <- 0
  for (i in v) {
    if (i == 1) {
      s <- s*2
    } else {
      s <- s + 1
    }
  }
  s
}
```

and then you can apply `replicate` to repeat the experiment, e.g.,

```
n <- 20
p <- 2/3
r <- replicate(1e6,f(n,p))
```

We will see

```
> mean(r)
[1] 629.074

> sd(r)
[1] 1326.681
```

Comment: The score is not stable. When I try f(10) the score varies with each launch.

Comment: @Jena Since `f(10,2/3)` is just a random variable. You need Monte Carlo simulation, e.g., `replicate(1e6,f(n,p))` to generate sufficient samples such that you can see the mean and standard deviation. Otherwise, one single random variable `f(n,p)` is meaningless.

Comment: I'm sorry if the question was not clear. But I updated. I don't know much R

Comment: > r
 [1]  376  540   53 6032  290  118 5408  541 8360  349
> r <- replicate(10,f(n,p))
> r
 [1] 522 632 380 696  63 258 201  48 116 164
> r <- replicate(10,f(n,p))
> r
 [1]  230 4182   69  637   39  140  173 1427  482  182